# Are the following to problems in RL complexity class?  Proof outline?

Tags: computational-complexity

1. L={(G,v)|G is an undirected graph containing at least one circle which itself contains vertex v}
2. R={(G,v)|G is an undirected graph containing at least one circle which itself contains vertex v, and at least one circle which itself does not contain vertex v}

Comment: What is RL complexity class?

Comment: RL = Randomized Logarithmic space:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL_%28complexity%29 .
This question is more suited to CS Theory StackExchange, 
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3):

In fact, since Reingold proved that STCONN is in L these languages are also in L.

The proof for the first is the following. For every u neighbor of v, delete the uv edge and check whether u and v are connected in the resulting graph. If yes, then there is a cycle. If the answer is no for all u, then there is no cycle containing v.

The proof of the second is similar, first check for a cycle containg v, then consider all the edges of v deleted and check whether there is a cycle in the remaining graph, e.g. as before for every pair of vertices.